# Unabled to load lohmann/json.hpp using CMake - getting fatal error: 'nlohmann/json.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following main.cpp, very simple script, trying to re-produce the problem and isolate to it's most basic.

```
#include<iostream>

#include<fmt/core.h>

// #include "json/json.hpp"
// #include <json/json.hpp>
// #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
// #include "json.hpp"
// #include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

int main(){
    fmt::print("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The commented out include statements are all of the paths I have tried to get this into my program.

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(main)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build)

# include(FetchContent)
# FetchContent_Declare(
#   json
#   GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/nlohmann/json
# )
# FetchContent_MakeAvailable(json)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(fmt
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt
    GIT_TAG 9.0.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(main json)
target_link_libraries(main fmt)
```

I've commented out the json part since it's not working obviously, I can also `json-src` and `json-build` in my `_deps` folder so I know for a fact that it is being downloaded into my local machine.

After running `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and `make` and then running the executable I get the error in the title `'nlohmann/json.hpp' file not found`

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried to reproduce the example with another popular C++ package which worked fine. Tried changing the include statements to see if maybe I had something wrong since I don't fully understand all the nuance with CMake and am quite new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either specifically use the interface target already included in the nlohmann library, which will automatically populate the correct include path for you, with:

```
target_link_libraries(main nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

Or you would need to specifically include the include path yourself:

```
include_directories(${json_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

With either way, you will be able to use `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>` in your source.

Comment: beautiful, that works! ... still a bit confused as to why I have to do it this way for this library but not for `fmt` or maybe eve `googletest`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @dsj-23 Would need to go through the cmake file to be sure, but I assume {fmt} uses the target name `fmt`, so you can simply `target_link_libraries(main fmt)`. If you fetched {fmt} as `format`, `target_link_libraries(main format)` probably won't work.

Comment: @dsj-23 In general, `include_directories(${xxx_SOURCE_DIR}/include_path)` should always work as `FetchContent` will always generate `xxx_SOURCE_DIR` for you, so you can manually add the include path.